# First Person Camera using JOGL GL3 core

Tags: camera, projection, jogl, vao

I am trying to make a basic first person camera scene using JOGL GL3 core and programmed vertex shader, but it doesn't look like the vertex array object is been correctly projected.

I believe the keyboard and mouse functions are working correctly and that the problem lies with shader program or vertex shader.

The AxisScene is where the bulk of the action happens, but the entire gradle project can be found [here](https://github.com/thatkow/fpsscene)

I followed the projection theory from [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html)

What code is wrong/missing to create true FPS behaviour?

```
package fpsscene.fpsscene;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2ES2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL3;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL3ES3;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLES3;
import com.jogamp.opengl.glu.GLU;
import com.jogamp.opengl.math.Matrix4;

import fpsscene.adapters.ApplyXY;
import fpsscene.adapters.BasicMovement;
import fpsscene.gl.primitives.ColoredTriangle;
import fpsscene.gl.primitives.Point2f;
import fpsscene.gl.primitives.Point3f;

public class AxisScene extends Scene implements ApplyXY , BasicMovement{

    private static String vertexShaderString = String.join("\n", 
            "#version 130\n",
            "",
            "in vec3 vertex_position;",
            "in vec3 vertex_colour;",
            "uniform mat4 view, proj;",
            "out vec3 colour;",
            "void main() {",
            "  colour = vertex_colour;",
            "  gl_Position =  proj * view * vec4 (vertex_position, 1.0);",
            "}"
            );

    private static String fragmentShaderString = String.join("\n", 
            "#version 130\n",
            "in vec3 colour;",
            "out vec4 frag_colour;",
            "void main() {",
            "  frag_colour = vec4 (colour, 1.0);",
            "}"
            );

    private int shaderProgram;
    int vertShader;
    int fragShader;
    int view_mat_location;
    int proj_mat_location;

    Matrix4 proj_mat;
    Matrix4 view_mat;

    float sens_rot;

    Point3f eye_default;
    Point3f up_default;
    Point2f rot_default;
    Point2f fov_default;
    Point3f eye;
    Point3f up;
    Point2f rot;
    Point2f fov;

    int axisVao[] = new int[1];
    private int axisLen;

    float near; // clipping plane
    float far; // clipping plane

    static final int COLOR_IDX = 0;
    static final int VERTICES_IDX = 1;
    private static final float DROT_FULL = 360.0f;
    private static final float DROT_QUART = DROT_FULL/4.0f; 
    private int width=1920;
    private int height=1080;

    public AxisScene() {
        this.eye_default = new Point3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        this.fov_default = new Point2f(120.0f, 90.0f);
        this.rot_default = new Point2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        this.up_default = new Point3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        this.eye = eye_default;
        this.fov = fov_default;
        this.rot = rot_default;
        this.up = up_default;

        near = 0.01f;
        far = 1000000.0f;
        sens_rot = 0.03f;


        rot.set(138.869919f, 4.44001198f);  
        eye.set(-4.66594696f,3.20000124f,-5.04626369f);
        //      rot.set(167.31528f,0.0f);



        updateProjMat();
        updateViewMatrix();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3();
        if(!gl.isGL3core()){
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "GL3core not enabled");
        }
        vertShader = createShaderFromString(gl, AxisScene.vertexShaderString,GL2ES2.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        fragShader = createShaderFromString(gl, AxisScene.fragmentShaderString,GL2ES2.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        shaderProgram = gl.glCreateProgram();
        gl.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertShader);
        gl.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragShader);
        gl.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        this.view_mat_location = gl.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
        this.proj_mat_location = gl.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "proj");
        gl.glDeleteShader(vertShader);
        gl.glDeleteShader(fragShader);

        List<ColoredTriangle> triangles = new AxisTrianges(100).createAxisTriangles();
        float[] vertices = ColoredTriangle.verticesToArray(triangles);
        float[] colors = ColoredTriangle.colorsToArray(triangles);
        FloatBuffer fbVertices = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertices);
        FloatBuffer fbColors = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(colors);

        int[] points_vbo = new int[1];
        gl.glGenBuffers(1, points_vbo,0);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, points_vbo[0]);
        gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangles.size() * 9 * Float.BYTES, fbVertices, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        int[] colours_vbo = new int[1];
        gl.glGenBuffers(1, colours_vbo,0);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colours_vbo[0]);
        gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangles.size() * 9 * Float.BYTES, fbColors, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.glGenVertexArrays(1, axisVao,0);
        gl.glBindVertexArray(axisVao[0]);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, points_vbo[0]);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0L);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colours_vbo[0]);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0L);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        axisLen = triangles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        System.out.println("cleanup, remember to release shaders");
        GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3();
        gl.glUseProgram(0);
        gl.glDetachShader(shaderProgram, vertShader);
        gl.glDeleteShader(vertShader);
        gl.glDetachShader(shaderProgram, fragShader);
        gl.glDeleteShader(fragShader);
        gl.glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.updateProjMat();
        GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3();
        gl.glViewport((width-height)/2,0,height,height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void glDisplay(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3();
        gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1.0f);  
        gl.glClear(GL2ES2.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT | GL2ES2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT   |    GL2ES2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT   );
        gl.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(this.view_mat_location, 1, false, this.view_mat.getMatrix(), 0);
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(this.proj_mat_location, 1, true, this.proj_mat.getMatrix(), 0);
        gl.glBindVertexArray(axisVao[0]);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL2ES2.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 * axisLen); //Draw the vertices as triangle
        gl.glBindVertexArray(0);
        gl.glCullFace(GL2ES2.GL_NONE);  
        gl.glDisable(GL2ES2.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }


    private void updateViewMatrix() {
        Matrix4 T = new Matrix4();
        T.translate(-eye.getX(), -eye.getY(), -eye.getZ());
        Matrix4 yRot = new Matrix4();
        yRot.rotate((float)Math.toRadians(rot.getX()), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        Matrix4 xRot = new Matrix4();
        xRot.rotate((float)Math.toRadians(Math.cos(-Math.toRadians(rot.getX())) * rot.getY()), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Matrix4 zRot = new Matrix4();
        zRot.rotate((float)Math.toRadians(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rot.getX())) * rot.getY()), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Matrix4 R = yRot;
        R.multMatrix(xRot);
        R.multMatrix(zRot);
        view_mat = T;
        view_mat.multMatrix(R);
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean glRender(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3();
        return false;
    }

    private void updateProjMat() {
        float aspect = (float) width / (float) height; // aspect ratio
        float range = (float) Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov.getX() * 0.5f));
        float proj_mat[] = new float[16];

        proj_mat[0] = 1.0f / (range * aspect);
        proj_mat[1] = 0.0f;
        proj_mat[2] = 0.0f;
        proj_mat[3] = 0.0f;

        proj_mat[4] = 0.0f;
        proj_mat[5] = 1.0f / range;
        proj_mat[6] = 0.0f;
        proj_mat[7] = 0.0f;

        proj_mat[8] = 0.0f;
        proj_mat[9] = 0.0f;
        proj_mat[10] = -(far + near) / (far - near);
        proj_mat[11] = -(2.0f * far * near) / (far - near);

        proj_mat[12] = 0.0f;
        proj_mat[13] = 0.0f;
        proj_mat[14] =-1.0f;
        proj_mat[15] = 0.0f;

        this.proj_mat = new Matrix4();
        this.proj_mat.multMatrix(proj_mat);
    }

    @Override
    public void applyXY(float x, float y) {     
        rot.setX(fmod(rot.getX() + x * sens_rot, DROT_FULL));
        rot.setY(Math.min(Math.max(rot.getY() + y * sens_rot, -DROT_QUART), DROT_QUART));
        updateViewMatrix();
    }

    private float fmod(float f, float m) {
        return ((f%m) + m) %m;
    }

    @Override
    public void translate(float x, float y, float z) {
        float deltax = z * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rot.getX())) + x * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rot.getX()));
        float deltaz = z * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rot.getX())) - x * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rot.getX()));
        eye.set( eye.getX()+deltax, eye.getY()+y, eye.getZ()+deltaz );
        updateViewMatrix();
        System.out.println(eye + rot.toString());
    }



    private int createShaderFromString(GL3 gl, String shaderCode,int type) {
        int shader =  gl.glCreateShader(type);;
        String[] vlines = new String[] { shaderCode };
        int[] vlengths = new int[] { vlines[0].length() };
        gl.glShaderSource(shader, vlines.length, vlines, vlengths, 0);
        gl.glCompileShader(shader);
        int[] compiled = new int[1];
        gl.glGetShaderiv(shader, GL2ES2.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled,0);
        if(compiled[0]!=0){
            System.out.println("Horray! vertex shader compiled");
        } else {
            int[] logLength = new int[1];
            gl.glGetShaderiv(shader, GL2ES2.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, logLength, 0);

            byte[] log = new byte[logLength[0]];
            gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, logLength[0], (int[])null, 0, log, 0);

            System.err.println("Error compiling the vertex shader: " + new String(log));
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return shader;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to follow first some general OpenGL tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to make a camera have "true FPS behavior" then I suggest you to take a look at this tutorial: [https://beta.wikiversity.org/wiki/Computer_graphics_--*2008-2009*--_info.uvt.ro/Laboratory_7](https://beta.wikiversity.org/wiki/Computer_graphics_--_2008-2009_--_info.uvt.ro/Laboratory_7)

I personally went with solution nº 2. From what iv'e seen of the solution you went with, this one seems a lot more elegant. Of course I modified it to include the mouse. If you want to try to do it yourself just try to follow whatever solution better adjusts to your code. If you want I can instead show you my code with the modifications done but only if you ask for it, since I don't want to spoil you the solution.

Comment: This source code uses an old subversion of JOGL 2. You'll have to update the import clauses. If you need some more complete examples, I advise you to look at the source code of my own first person shooter: http://tuer.sourceforge.net